# Annoying problem with the "with" clause in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using this function to replace some strings from access in a word document. This function works pretty well

```
Sub reemplazar(doc As Word.Document, after As String, before As String, replaceall As Boolean)
    With doc.Content.Find
        .Text = after 
        .Replacement.Text = before 
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        If replaceall Then
            .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Else
            .Execute replace:=wdReplaceOne
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

But... I don't know why if I rewrite the function in this way it stop working. There is no error or warning, but the replacement are not made.

```
Sub reemplazar(doc As Word.Document, after As String, before As String, replaceall As Boolean)
    doc.Content.Find.Text = after 
    doc.Content.Find.Replacement.Text = before 
    With doc.Content.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        If replaceall Then
            .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Else
            .Execute replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone explain what is the difference between this two snippets or why the second one is not working propertly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Find property returns a Find object every time you call it.  So in your second code snippet you're

1. Creating a Find object and setting its Text property
2. Creating a new Find object and setting its Replacement.Text property
3. Creating a third Find object and setting a bunch of other properties and executing

That last executed Find object doesn't have it's Text or Replacement.Text properties set.  If you wanted to use it in this manner, you could create an object variable like

```
Sub reemplazar(doc As Word.Document, after As String, before As String, replaceall As Boolean)

    Dim fnd As Find

    Set fnd = doc.Content.Find

    fnd.Text = after
    fnd.Replacement.Text = before
    With fnd
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        If replaceall Then
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Else
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Right answer-cause and answer-code. You could&should make it clear that you're enumerating problems of the 2nd code snippet.

Comment: Ugh. I'm sure you're right, but it is quite revolting that accessing a property creates a new object each time.

Comment: @Vicky ugh, not really, if you mean that the Find method returns a object, that has more to do with the fact your not using initialising a strongly typed object to the return value from your Find method. then expecting the property values of two different implicitly typed objects to maintain state between each other... hmm.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an actual true cut and paste of your code? These two should work identically. Are you sure there isn't something else going on like odd line endings?

(I notice in the first example your `End If` is not indented correctly, but I doubt that's anything to do with it)

Comment: Yes, this is really a copy of my code. I also think that this two functions should work identically...It's suppossed that the WITH clause is only syntactic sugar. This is the reason of my question and the reason of my headache. Thanks!